# Why is my Java bit check on byte unstable?

Tags: java, byte, bit

I had a little utility method for checking whether a bit is set on a byte:

```
public static boolean get(byte b, int bit) {
    return (b & (1 << bit)) > 0;
}
```

For 4 years this thing didn't seem to give me any trouble.
Now in my code a byte class-member is initialized by using DataInput.readByte() of a DataInput passed to the constructor of the class (the class is an inner-class). I have another piece of code that does exactly the same thing and never gave any trouble. It goes sorta like this:

```
public class A {

    public class B {

        public byte x;

        public B(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            x = in.readByte();
            if (Utility.get(x, 7)) {
                y = in.readInt();
                ...
                etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now with the new code the utility method mostly returns true but sometimes false for the same arguments (when printed these are b=-124 and bit=7). I checked that no other Threads are accessing the byte member variable that is passed as 'b' (shouldn't be possible anyway since all of this happens in the class' constructor). Also if I print out the passed value for 'b' in the utility method (for example) the issue goes away. It seems to be timing related (that's why I thought of Threads).

After reading up I realized that (b & 0b10000000) cast as a byte is -128 but (b & 0b10000000) cast as an int is 128. Still I would expect the utility method to return the same result for same 'b' and 'bit'. Now after changing my utility method to:

```
public static boolean get(byte b, int bit) {
    return (b & (1 << bit)) != 0;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine. My question why does the first version give different results for the same arguments? For b=-124 and bit=7 it seems to evaluate (b & (1 << bit)) sometimes as +128 and sometimes as -128??? depending on??? I'm running open JDK 12.0.2.

EDIT1: I don't have any code I can simply paste here that does what I state (yet) but here's some code to demonstrate what I mean by the sign of an expression changing depending on casting to byte or int (This isn't an issue for me, I understand that the Java byte primitive is signed etc.):

```
    byte b = -124;
    System.out.println((int)(b & 0b10000000));
    System.out.println((byte)(b & 0b10000000));
    System.out.println(((int)(b & 0b10000000) > 0));
    System.out.println(((byte)(b & 0b10000000) > 0));
```

Result:

```
128
-128
true
false
```

I'm just considering that for some reason, that part of the expression in my utility method is sometimes cast to byte and sometimes to int (because that would explain the different results).

EDIT2: I have something that can reproduce the issue. There are 3 class files (ByteCheckTest.java, Foo.java and Util.java) all in the bytechecktest package:

First ByteCheckTest.java:

```
package bytechecktest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Random;

public class ByteCheckTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        
            File file = new File(applicationDirectory(ByteCheckTest.class).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "output.dat");
        
            //Instantiate first Foo and initialize it with 100 random Bars.
            Foo f1 = new Foo();
            Random rnd = new Random(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                f1.addBar((byte)(-128 + rnd.nextInt(256)));
            }
            //Save the first Foo.
            f1.save(file);
        
            //Load a new Foo instance from the saved data and compare it to the original Foo (f1).
            Foo.load(file, f1, n);
        
        }
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    }

    //This is just to obtain the directory this app is in, to put the output.dat file in.
    static File applicationDirectory(Class<?> main_class) {
        File dir = null;
        try {
            dir = new File(main_class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).getParentFile();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dir;
    }

}
```

Then Foo.java

```
package bytechecktest;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Foo {

    class Bar {
    
        byte value;
        Bar sub;
        
        Bar(byte value) {
            this.value = value;
            if (isSet()) {
                sub = new Bar((byte)0);
            } else {
                sub = null;
            }
        }
        
        Bar(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            value = in.readByte();
            if (isSet()) {
                sub = new Bar(in);
            } else {
                sub = null;
            }
        }
        
        void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeByte(value);
            if (isSet()) {
                sub.write(out);
            }
        }
        
        boolean isSet() {
            return Util.get(value, 7);
        }
        
        void compare(String pre, Bar orig) {
            if (value != orig.value) {
                throw new RuntimeException("FAILED: " + pre + " " + value + "=" + orig.value);
            }
            if (isSet()) {
                sub.compare(pre + ".sub", orig.sub);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Bar> bars;
    
    Foo() {
        bars = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    Foo(DataInput in, Foo orig, int run) throws IOException {
        this();
        int n = in.readInt();
        if (orig.bars.size() != n) {
            throw new RuntimeException("FAILED: run" + run + " Loading Foo bars.size=" + n + " orig.bars.size=" + orig.bars.size());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Bar b = new Bar(in);
            b.compare("run" + run + ".bar[" + i + "]", orig.bars.get(i));
            bars.add(b);
        }
    }

    void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(bars.size());
        for (Bar b : bars) {
            b.write(out);
        }
    }
    
    void save(File f) {
        try {
            if (f.exists()) {
                f.delete();
            }
            DataOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));
                write(out);
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    static Foo load(File f, Foo orig, int run) {
        Foo foo;
        try {
            DataInputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)));
                foo = new Foo(in, orig, run);
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return foo;
    }
    
    void addBar(byte v) {
        bars.add(new Bar(v));
    }

}
```

Last, Util.java:

```
package bytechecktest;

public class Util {

    public static boolean get(byte b, int bit) {
        return (b & (1 << bit)) > 0; //Changing '>' here to '!=' makes the test succeed.
    }
    
}
```

ByteCheckTest.java runs the exact same test for the exact same values, 100 times. For me, on openJDK 12.0.2, this fails at some run of the test (with me not immediately the first run but iteration 55 for example).

But if I change the greater-than operator in `Util.get(byte, int)` for `!=` then the test runs fine the full 100 times.

Comment: SUGGESTION: `return ((1 << bit) & b) != 0`

Comment: @paulsm4 why is that better?

Comment: Can you add a full code example that returns a nondeterministic result? I'm finding it very hard to believe that running the same code twice without external input or random numbers would generate a different outcome. If adding a print statement is what changes the result, then please paste the two code examples that differ.

Comment: @Pieter12345: I completely agree- we need a full example.  The OP's contention that his expression is "non-deterministic" is nonsense.  I was merely suggesting that checking for ">0" is silly ... if all he needs to know is "0" or "nonzero" ... and if reverting to a negative int might be a factor.

Comment: Incidentally 0x10000000 is a hex literal. You meant 0b10000000

Comment: @paulsm4 That reason for your suggestion is confusing, as your suggestion is logically equivalent to the code he said he replaced the first example with. Only the arguments of the bitwise AND are swapped, so it looks like that swap was your suggestion.

Comment: `0b10000000 cast as an int is 128`. No it isn't. It is `0x7fffff80`. I don't know why you would even write a method as trivial as these. It is not possible for this code or indeed any such code to behave as you allege. Evidence please.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks! I changed it.

Comment: It could only be a JIT compiler bug from java byte code to real machine code. But my first assumption would be that `bit < 0` or `bit > 7` So `1 << (bit & 7)`. _That_ error would result in too many `true`s becaise of byte's sign extension.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks Joop! I don't think bit could be the problem because I call the utility method like this `Utility.get(b,7);` (that is, with a integer literal). I'm trying to write a small program that does it as we speak but thus far no luck.

Comment: I've added code for a small program that for me (openJDK 12.0.2 reproduces the issue). A test runs 100 times (exactly the same) but fails somewhere at the n-th iteration unless you change the '>' in Util.get(...) for '!=', then all 100 iterations of the test just run fine.

Comment: Just ran my own test under jre1.8.0.241 both using `>` or `!=` run fine for 1000 iterations. I think it's a bug in jdk12.0.2. (So useful since we're at 17).

Comment: Download openJDK 17.0.1 and like jre1.8.0.241 it runs fine for 1000 iterations regardless of using '>' or '!='. So I'm pretty sure it was a bug in jdk12.0.2 that has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the issue is due to a bug in openJDK 12.0.2. I've tested the above program in jre1.8.0.241, openJDK12.0.2 and openJDK17.0.1 (using a 1000 iterations) and only running it on openJDK12.0.2 fails (at the 55th iteration) if I replace '!=' for '>'.
I can't find which bug that might have been.

Answer (score 1):

The two methods return the same values.

```
public static boolean get1(byte b, int bit) {
    return (b & (1 << bit)) > 0;
}

public static boolean get2(byte b, int bit) {
    return (b & (1 << bit)) != 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = Byte.MIN_VALUE; i <= Byte.MAX_VALUE; ++i) {
        byte b = (byte)i;
        for (int k = 0; k <= 8; ++k)
            if (get1(b, k) != get2(b, k))
                System.out.println(b + " " + k);
    }
}
```

output:

```
(nothing)
```

There is a difference when the value of `bit` is 31.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I've added code above that for me reproduces the issue.